# Query Returns Multiple Rows Instead of the max

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table in Access with the relevant fields EFTRecID, EFTRecIDNum and CreatedBy. EFTRecIDNum is an auto number field, and EFTRecID concatenates the required format of "CE" & EFTRedIDNum. I am attempting to return the highest value in the EFTRecID field that was created by the current user. To do this I am trying to do a sub query that finds the Max(EFTRecIDNum) WHERE Created = my name. However instead of returning the max, it is returning all values with my name. I know I could use the format option to just format the EFTRecIDNum field, but I need to be able to search in the format CE456.

TL;DR: Query returns all records with my name, rather then max with my name.

```
Public Sub DownloadMyRecords()

    Dim intI As Integer 'Used for looping in a variety of locations

    strSQL = "SELECT EFTRecID FROM tblEFTRec WHERE (SELECT MAX(EFTRecIDNum) FROM tblEFTRec WHERE CreatedBy = '" & Application.UserName & "')"

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    With cnn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbLocation & "\" & dbName & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & DBPWord
        .Open dbLocation & "\" & dbName
    End With

    Debug.Print strSQL

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    rst.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
             CursorType:=adOpenForwardOnly, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
             Options:=adCmdText

    Debug.Print (rst.GetString)

    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: No matter you select the max of anything in the "WHERE" clause, it won't return just one record... It's just a "filter" for the resultset (i.e. you say "return me ALL records, where 'EFTRecIDNum' carries the biggest number). If you want 1 result, see the answers below, or use "SELECT TOP 1 [same]", but remember, this just narrows (limits) a full and complete resultset, the statement still be no good if it should return just one value

Comment: @Mark thanks for taking the time to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this SQL statement instead:

```
strSQL = "SELECT EFTRecID 
FROM tblEFTRec 
WHERE EFTRecIDNum = (SELECT MAX(EFTRecIDNum) FROM tblEFTRec WHERE CreatedBy = '" & Application.UserName & "')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
"SELECT EFTRecID FROM tblEFTRec 
WHERE EFTRecIDNum = (SELECT MAX(EFTRecIDNum) FROM tblEFTRec 
    WHERE CreatedBy = '" & Application.UserName & "')"
```

Is there a reason the following doesn't work?

```
"SELECT MAX(EFTRecID) FROM tblEFTRec 
WHERE CreatedBy = '" & Application.UserName & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks JJ32, the first option worked perfectly. I will mark as correct once enough time passes. Just as an fyi, the second won't work because EFTRecID is alphanumeric, where EFTRecIDNum is only the numeric portion.